# d3.js Dendrogram: How to toggle visibility of nodes by click

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm new at d3-js and I want to use "d3.js Dendrogram" in order to display an 
organization tree. Thanks to the demo, I could display all of 
hierarchy. However, I can not find how to toggle visibility of nodes 
when I click upper nodes. Does anyone knows any samples or references? 
Any help will be appreciated.

http://mbostock.github.com/d3/ex/cluster.html

Comment: I found "http://bl.ocks.org/1249394" from among official references. I 
will check the sample whether I can use it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I believe "[The Power Rank](http://thepowerrank.com/visual/NCAA_Tournament_Predictions)" example can help you with this.  This uses a radial tree, which I believe is nothing more than a radial Dendrogram, to lay things out.  You'll notice that all nodes in a hierarchical path can be selected at the same time.

I believe it has to do with how you tag each node with the appropriate attribute (an ID or Class) that you can select by, on mouse over or on mouse click.

I hope it helps.

Good Luck,

Frank

Answer (score 0):

In my case I ended using a collapsible tree instead of dendrogram for almost the same purpose. See http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4339083